# Keeping float value decimal places in an awk script

Tags: bash, awk

I have this line using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{
                 for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
                   if ($i+0 != $i)
                     $i = temp[i]+0.00
                   temp[i]=$i+0.00
                }}1'
```

In short, this converts every word to the last seen number of that column.

**THE PROBLEM**

The issue is that the decimals place of every value that comes out of `$i = temp[i]+0.00` loses its decimals precision.

For example,

```
-ERROR -1.57 -2.02 
-2.10 2.70 ERROR
-4.70 ERROR -0.52 
-2.20 ERROR -0.02 
-2.20 -1.50 ERROR
```

Turns into:

```
0 -1.57 -2.02 
-2.10 2.70 -2.02
-4.70 2.7 -0.52 
-2.20 2.7 -0.02 
-2.20 -1.50 -0.02
```

`2.70` would become `2.7` and so every word that directly follows `2.70` would not be turned into `2.70`, but instead into `2.7`. How can you force awk to save a float value to a set amount of decimal places?

Obviously, `+0.00` didn't help.

Comment: There's no difference between `2.70` and `2.7` in floating point.

Comment: What's this `$(`? Is this your prompt?

Comment: @markp-fuso this was my attempt at fixing it, but obviously didn't work. I'll just remove it if it causes confusion.

Comment: Just curious - why do you care? The data isn't aligned visually anyway and the value's the same whether it's displayed as 2.7 or 2.70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refrain from performing math on the values which in turn disables `awk` from making decisions on how many digits of accuracy to maintain; instead, just save each value as is (effectively save as a string).

Consider:

```
$ printf "1 1.1 1.02 1.003 1.0004 1.00005\na b c d e f\n" 
1 1.1 1.02 1.003 1.0004 1.00005
a b c d e f
```

A few tweaks to OP's current `awk` code:

```
$ printf "1 1.1 1.02 1.003 1.0004 1.00005\na b c d e f\n" | awk '
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      if ($i+0 != $i)
         $i = (i in temp ? temp[i] : 0)
      temp[i]=$i
   }
} 1'
1 1.1 1.02 1.003 1.0004 1.00005
1 1.1 1.02 1.003 1.0004 1.00005
```

Coming back to OP's sample data ...

Adding some more lines to the sample data set:

```
$ cat sample.dat
-ERROR -1.57 -2.02
-2.10 2.70 ERROR
-4.70 ERROR -0.52
-2.20 ERROR -0.02
-2.20 -1.50 ERROR
-3.333 0.1234 -0.02
ERROR ERROR ERROR
-2.10 2.70 ERROR
-4.70 ERROR -0.52
```

Running the modified `awk` code:

```
awk '
{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
      if ($i+0 != $i)
         $i = (i in temp ? temp[i] : 0)
      temp[i]=$i
   }
}1' sample.dat
```

This generates:

```
0 -1.57 -2.02
-2.10 2.70 -2.02
-4.70 2.70 -0.52
-2.20 2.70 -0.02
-2.20 -1.50 -0.02
-3.333 0.1234 -0.02
-3.333 0.1234 -0.02
-2.10 2.70 -0.02
-4.70 2.70 -0.52
```

If this doesn't address the issue then we'll need to see more sample data that more accurately reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(int($i)){
      val=(val?val OFS:"") $i
      arr[i]=$i
    }
    else{
      val=(val?val OFS:"") (i in arr?arr[i]:0)
    }
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```